# Parallel ForEach wait 500 ms before spawning

Tags: c#, .net, plinq

I have this situation:

```
var tasks = new List<ITask> ...
Parallel.ForEach(tasks, currentTask => currentTask.Execute() );
```

Is it possible to instruct PLinq to wait for 500ms before the next thread is spawned?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would assume `Parallel.ForEach(tasks, currentTask => { Thread.Sleep(5000); currentTask.Execute(); });` would do the trick, but I would be interested into knowing why you are trying to do this - sounds like a workaround for something?

Comment: Each task, which takes a while to execute, gets its data from another resource which can only be hit every 0.5 second. I guess I could separate getting the data and executing the task ...

Comment: No this may fail anytime, dont assume it will finish within 500 ms, you can make use of `WaitHandles` here

Comment: Separation would be the first choice here.

Comment: Yeah just realized this. The latest implementation works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `Parallel.Foreach` totally wrong, You should make a special Enumerator that rate limits itself to getting data once every 500 ms.

I made some assumptions on how your [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) works due to you not providing any details.

```
private IEnumerator<SomeResource> GetRateLimitedResource()
{
    SomeResource someResource = null;
    do
    {
        someResource = _remoteProvider.GetData();

        if(someResource != null)
        {
             yield return someResource;
             Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    } while (someResource != null);
}
```

here is how your paralell should look then

```
Parallel.ForEach(GetRateLimitedResource(), SomeFunctionToProcessSomeResource);
```

Comment: Nice idea because it is simple yet powerful.

Comment: This waits 500 ms before the first item is retrieved. Is that intentional?

Comment: @svick I had to put the sleep somewhere, I moved to to after the data grab so it will sleep then. The code could be improved further by taking a `DateTime.Now` and saving it in a local variable, then when the next iteration happens you can check to see if the 500 ms has passed and only sleep the required amount of time.

Comment: This will probably not work as expected, because AFAIK the `Parallel.ForEach` employs chunk partitioning by default. Meaning that progressively will enumerate more and more elements at a time. Chunk partitioning makes sense when it's desirable to reduce the synchronization overhead, but in this case the overhead is completely dwarfed by the imposed artificial delay. So it makes sense to disable it, by replacing the `GetRateLimitedResource()` with the `Partitioner.Create(GetRateLimitedResource(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are already some good suggestions. I would agree with others that you are using PLINQ in a manner it wasn't meant to be used.

My suggestion would be to use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). This is probably better than writing a method that returns an `IEnumerable<>` that forces a half second delay, because you may not need to wait the full half second, depending on how much time has passed since your last API call.

With the timer, it will invoke a delegate that you've provided it at the interval you specify, so even if the first task isn't done, a half second later it will invoke your delegate on another thread, so there won't be any extra waiting.

From your example code, it sounds like you have a list of tasks, in this case, I would use [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to keep track of the tasks. Once the queue is empty, turn off the timer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) instead.

```
var task = tasks.Aggregate((t1, t2) =>
                                t1.ContinueWith(async _ =>
                                    { Thread.Sleep(500); return t2.Result; }));
```

If you don't want the tasks chained then there is also the overload to [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) assuming the tasks are in order of delay.

```
var tasks = Enumerable
              .Range(1, 10)
              .Select(x => Task.Run(() => x * 2))
              .Select((x, i) => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i * 500))
                                    .ContinueWith(_ => x.Result));

foreach(var result in tasks.Select(x => x.Result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

From the comments a better options would be to guard the resource instead of using the time delay.

```
static object Locker = new object();

static int GetResultFromResource(int arg)
{
    lock(Locker)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return arg * 2;
    }
}

var tasks = Enumerable
          .Range(1, 10)
          .Select(x => Task.Run(() => GetResultFromResource(x)));

foreach(var result in tasks.Select(x => x.Result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Kind of answers the question but removes all concurrency.

Comment: I added another method that will run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

In this case how about a Producer-Consumer pattern with a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx)?

```
var tasks = new BlockingCollection<ITask>();

// add tasks, if this is an expensive process, put it out onto a Task
// tasks.Add(x);

// we're done producin' (allows GetConsumingEnumerable to finish)
tasks.CompleteAdding();

RunTasks(tasks);
```

With a single consumer thread:

```
static void RunTasks(BlockingCollection<ITask> tasks)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        task.Execute();

        // this may not be as accurate as you would like
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

If you have access to .Net 4.5 you can use [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx):

```
static void RunTasks(BlockingCollection<ITask> tasks)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Task.Delay(500)
            .ContinueWith(() => task.Execute())
            .Wait();
    }
}
```